# TeamCity VCS triggers with 2 solutions in a TFS Project

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a project in TFS that has 2 solution files in the folder. One is for the website, the other is for a web API:

Project Name
Project Name / Main
Project Name / Main / Shared Project Folder 1
Project Name / Main / Shared Project Folder 2
Project Name / Main / Website Folder
Project Name / Main / WebApi Folder
Project Name / Main / Website.sln
Project Name / Main / WebAPI.sln

This structure is because the 2 solutions have a couple of shared projects.

TeamCity (version 9) is detecting the check in and building the Website & API, regardless of which solution files have been changed.

Is there a way to configure TeamCity to detect the projects that have changed and run the appropriate builds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with TC9 (I use TC8) but I'd say create two build configurations:

- Build Configuration A (Website)

  This one would have build steps to build Website.sln only
- Build Configuration B (WebApi)

  This one would have build steps to build WeApi.sln only

Then for config A add a VCS trigger with a trigger rule like this:

+:WebSite/**
+:WebSite.sln

Then for config B add a VCS trigger

+:WebApi/**
+:WebApi.sln

Build config A will only be triggered when changes in Website folder or Website.sln itself are detected.

Build config B will only be triggered when changes in WebApi folder or WebApi.sln itself are detected.